# Axios is returning HTML instead of JSON for only one function in program

Tags: node.js, json, express, axios, crud

I'm building a small CRUD app with the MEVN stack that keeps track of students. The repsponse is outputting in HTML and not JSON:

**Mongo Model**

```
var StudentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  first: String,
  last: String,
  teacher: String,
  classroom: String,
  major: String,
  minor: String,
  updated_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});
```

**Express Router**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Book.find(function (err, products) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(products);
  });
});
```

**Student List Component**

```
created () {
    axios.get(`/student`)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      this.students = response.data
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)
    })
  },
```

Every time I call the "students" route to get a list of all of the students, I get `reponse.data` returning as HTML instead of JSON.

**Returned data (HTML)**

```
<title>mevn-stack</title>
<script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/manifest.d39e40457f281fdf3544.js></script>
<script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/vendor.a0442dcc64c824d931ee.js></script>
<script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/app.b0051853730faf43e49b.js></script>
```

**Console error**

> s.foreach is not a function

**Update**

This is the output of stringifying the response in the Student List Component as recommended by @JoelHager

```
{
  "data": "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8><meta name=viewport content=\"width=device-width,initial-scale=1\"><title>mevn-stack</title><link href=/static/css/app.ae61a91c1a891593d309fd6551053eab.css rel=stylesheet></head><body><div id=app></div><script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/manifest.a9cf3b120af2eaf30b2a.js></script><script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/vendor.7f820bcda7e516bfce3e.js></script><script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/app.a88ae44d36b2723e3a14.js></script></body></html>",
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK",
  "headers": {
    "accept-ranges": "bytes",
    "cache-control": "public, max-age=0",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "content-length": "512",
    "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
    "date": "Fri, 24 Apr 2020 10:00:40 GMT",
    "etag": "W/\"200-171aba15734\"",
    "last-modified": "Fri, 24 Apr 2020 10:00:09 GMT",
    "x-powered-by": "Express"
  },
  "config": {
    "transformRequest": {},
    "transformResponse": {},
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    },
    "method": "get",
    "url": "/student/"
  },
  "request": {}
}
```

Comment: In your resp, use JSON.stringify() and tell me what it does

Comment: Sorry @JoelHager, this is my first time making a CRUD app. Where at exactly?

Comment: .then( (response) => JSON.stringify(response)

Comment: Then log it to console and check it